# Oracle SQL Subquery Syntax Error caused by ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, ora-00907

I have a syntax error on an Oracle SQL query. The query should get me the department of an employee. If the employee has no department (null), I want the department of the first manager up the hierarchy, which has a department.

```
SELECT department_id FROM department
WHERE department_id =
(
    SELECT department_id FROM employee
    WHERE department_id IS NOT NULL AND rownum = 1
    start WITH employee_id = 19
    connect by employee_id = prior manager_id
    ORDER BY level
);
```

The error message is this:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 2
```

I have written an alternative query, which does the job. But I'm not very happy with it.

```
SELECT department_id FROM department
WHERE department_id = 
(
    SELECT department_id FROM employee
    WHERE level =
    (
        SELECT MIN(level) FROM employee
        WHERE department_id IS NOT NULL
        start WITH employee_id = 19
        connect by employee_id = prior manager_id
    )
    start WITH employee_id = 19
    connect by employee_id = prior manager_id
);
```

Do you have any idea how to fix the first query? Or to simplify the second one? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you don't need an ordering within the subquery. Just remove `ORDER BY level`.

Comment: Can I be sure, that I get the employee with the lowest level in the hierarchy (where the department is not null)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first query as correctly said by @Barbaros that `ORDER BY` is not needed and even `rownum = 1` will not do what you are thinking.

Does the following query fulfill your requirements:

```
SELECT
    E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    CASE WHEN E.DEPARTMENT_ID IS NOT NULL 
         THEN E.DEPARTMENT_ID
         ELSE LAG(D.DEPARTMENT_ID IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY LEVEL)
    END AS DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM
    EMPLOYEE E
    LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
START WITH E.EMPLOYEE_ID = 19
CONNECT BY E.EMPLOYEE_ID = PRIOR E.MANAGER_ID
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that did the trick for me. Although I had to adapt the query to work under Oracle 10g. **Line 5:** `ELSE first_value(D.DEPARTMENT_ID ignore nulls) OVER(ORDER BY LEVEL rows between 1 following and unbounded following)`